# Independence of Hilbert-space-valued random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Let $X,Y$ be two independent random variables taking values in a separable Hilbert space $U$.

Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if for all $u,v\in U$, $(X,u)$ and $(Y,v)$ are independent, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the inner product in $U$.

The 'only if' part is not difficult, so my question is how to prove the 'if' part. I wonder whether I can achieve it using characteristic function, i.e., to show
$$\mathbb{E}e^{i[(u,X)+(v,Y)]}=\mathbb{E}e^{i(u,X)}e^{i(v,Y)}$$ for all $u,v\in U$. But this is obvious.

I don't know whether the equality above is sufficient to derive that $X,Y$ are independent. When they are real-valued random variable, this is ture.

At last, can someone offer a textbook or lecture concerning about infinite dimensional random variable? I am learning SPDE, but few of the texbooks have introdution to r.v. of infinite dimension.

Comment: Gaussian Measures on Banach spaces by H H Kuo. Probability on Banach spaces by Ladoux and Talagrand.

Comment: Your result is true and it is proved by showing that the joint law of $(X,Y)$ and the product of the marginals coincide on cylinder sets, hence on Borel sets.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you very much!